# Don't allow image to grow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm trying to insert a image in a bootstrap navbar using flexbox, but the image is too big and flexbox grows more than navbar size making it ugly. How can I restrict the image size in order to make it's height as big as the other button's height (Or maybe just a little bit bigger)?
[image: Wrong img]
Code:

```html
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand">Resano Innovación</a>
      
      <div class="flexbox">
          <a class="nav-link active rounded" aria-current="page">Inicio</a>
          <a class="nav-link">Ubicación</a>
          <a class="nav-link">Contacto</a>
        
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="../img/eng.png" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: you could wrap the image in a container and set max-width / max-height

Comment: max-height and width is 100%, so it will show image's original size. Change it to the pixels. max-height:10px;

Comment: @ramilabbaszade that solution is not responsive, right?

Comment: Mostly sites don't change flags' sizes for different screens. Giving suitable pixels will be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put image in a div and give height and width for the responsive screen size. Also if you give **img** element a style like this it will be a responsive image.

```
  .img-div { 
  //assuming that you create this div and put image inside of it
     max-width:200px;
     height:100px;
   }


  img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  object-fit:cover;
  }
```